# Salesforce Field Service Lightning > Service Appointment is not appearing on the Mobile App

Tags: field-service-lightning

Service resource 'Jane Cando' have been assigned a service appointment with a parent WO. The service appointment is being displayed in the Gannt chart and scheduled for 20-June-2022. When I login with this user in the mobile app (Andriod), the appointment is not available. I did all the configuration and setup available in the [document](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_field_service_implementation_guide.pdf) (page 309-3011). Also followed this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000353016&type=1) from Salesforce but still issue is not resolved. Please can you advise what can be wrong here?

Current Setup:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

OWD settings for both SA and WO are Private.

**Update**
I figured that once I assign System Administrator profile to this service resource then appointment starts appearing but when I assign Standard User profile then it does not appear. Need to figure out which permission(s) is missing..

Comment: Have you been able to figure out which permission(s) is missing ?
I'm facing the exact same issue with some of my service resources.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have these settings in place under Field service Mobile Settings/Field service Settings.

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]
2. Permission set assignments as shown below for a mobile worker user
   in your org.

   [image]
3. [Install the connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mfs_prepare.htm&type=5)
4. It could also be because the Service Resource record is not "shared"
   anymore (or should better say "linked" correctly anymore) with the
   User record.  In my experience, this can happen because of: - The
   user record being (temporarily) "Deactivated"  (checkbox "Active"
   set to false) - The flag "Active" on the "Service Resource" record
   being set to "false".  We figured out the following workaround that
   reliably seemed to work for us (and then obviously "shares" the
   Service Resource record again with your user):

   1. Open the User record and make sure that the flag "active" is checked(= true)
   2. Open and edit the affected "Service Resource" record, and Change the
      linked user record to another, active user in your org. Save.
   3. Edit the Service Resource record again, and change the user back to
      your original, correct user + make sure the flag "Active" is set to
      true. Save.
   4. On Field Service Mobile App:  clear your cache  (settings > advanced
      settings > clear cache) and close and reopen the Mobile App.
   5. Login with your Field Crew user on the Mobile App. >>> this now
      should work again.
5. Refer: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000C6rJaSAJ